# Python, return new line in function return

Tags: python, flask

I have code like this `

```
celldata=""
        count=0
        for tableData in y:
            count = count+1
            strcount=str(count)
            celldata += strcount + ")" + tableData .text + "\n"
        return celldata
```

`
I am returning the value to be used in flask, the issue is I want each for loop row in a new line but after trying \n, and in the flask web app I am getting celldata in one single line with one space each between each output line of the for loop.
Here is my current output for celldata in flask web
1)xxxx 2)yyyy

I want the flask web url to return

```
1)xxxx
2)yyyy
```

Comment: It's not python, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to format this as HTML, I would suggest you add `<br />` also to the returned text:

```
celldata = []

for count, tableData in enumerate(y, start=1):
    celldata.append('{}) {}<br/>'.format(count, tableData.text))

return '\n'.join(celldata)
```

This first builds a list of entries with the correct numbering, and then joins each line together with a newline. The newline is purely cosmetic and will only effect how the HTML appears when viewed as source. It is the `<br />` which will ensure each entry appears on a different line.

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) is used to automatically count your entries for you.

Comment: hi - Thanks for the help. when i use this return render_template('hello.html', value=count,agents='\n'.join(celldata)) ,i get something like 1)XXXX<br/> in the flask web url. However if i just use return '\n'.join(celldata) , the <br/> is removed, how can i remove <br> using render template?

Answer (score 2):

You're presumably returning HTML, and viewing that HTML in a browser.

In HTML, all runs of whitespace are equivalent—there's no difference between `'\n'` and `' '`. The browser should convert them all to single spaces, and then decide how to flow the results nicely.

So, you're going to have to learn some basic HTML. But here are a few quick hints to get you started:

- `<p>one paragraph</p> <p>another paragraph</p>` defines two separate paragraphs.
- `<p>one paragraph<br />with a line break in the middle</p>` defines a paragraph with a line break in the middle.
- `<table><tr><td>row one</td></tr> <tr><td>row two</td></tr></table>` defines a table of two rows (and one column).

The last one is the most complicated, but given that you've got things named `tableData` and `celldata`, I suspect it may be what you actually want here.

HTML itself only specifies "structure", not layout. It's up to the browser to decide what "two paragraphs" or "a line break" or "two rows" actually means in terms of actual pixels. If you want finer control, you need to learn CSS as well as HTML, which lets you specify explicit styles for these elements.